# Whoosh returns empty results on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using Haystack+Whoosh to build the search feature in my django project.
On localhost the search was working fine and it returned result. Although I sometime noticed it returned indexes of some "object not found" while filtering.
But this is not my main problem. The main problem is when I tried deploying my app on heroku. The search is fine only after creating the database and on checking the next day it results are always empty. 
I tried "rebuild_index" and "update_index" command, but with no hope. I had to drop the database and re-sync it for it to work for sometime before stopping to work again

Any ideas what could cause this problem ??

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because of [Heroku's read-only filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem).

Comment: can u please further explain, because I still don't understand the problem ??

Comment: With Heroku you don't have a permanent filesystem to write to. Whoosh needs to write it's index to a filesystem. You would need to buy one of Heroku's addons like Websolr. You could try storing your Whoosh index on S3 or something, but, that would likely negate the benefit of having a search index in the first place.

Comment: ok, so I think I should switch to something like solr or elasticsearch as my backend engine ??

Comment: I've never done it myself, but yes, you're likely going to spend an extra $20/mo for the solr or elastic  "addon" and then you should be able to specify the backend in django-haystack.

Comment: @SalmaHamed I'm having this same problem. Do you have tips on what you ended up doing?

Comment: NO, I switched to elastic search